# No Holds – a barred crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
1. Country girls finally returning home after being swallowed by snake (6)
6. Strong desire to omit essential part in writing important text (1,5)
11. Error usually eliminated within split seconds (4)
12. The woman's a stepmother to 21 across? (4)
14. Leave one's country to golf in Abu Dhabi? (8)
15. After getting rid of the EU, the continent is secure (4)
16. Newspaper editor was very angry (5)
17. Play back a number of disco's #1 recordings (5)
18. One dictator, in an extreme fashion, is lead to Elba (5)
19. Mother to 26 across, you said? (3)
21. Greek deity protecting the hearts of hunters, animals and maids? (7)
24. Lack of sulphur in Sy's bean product – therefore, it goes up and down (2-2)
26. Farm animal's escape picked up (4)
29. Legends of 38 down that's stolen by Nazis (7)
31. Umbrian's first number (3)
32. For example, 5 down is less unsettled after the beginning of independence (5)
35. Members of The Police backing works by lead singer (5)
36. Mother caught attention showing Tolkien's horse (5)
37. Piece of weaponry shipped; regiment finally moving towards the front (4)
39. Island dweller gives up south for north, becoming one living far from the sea (8)
40. Central among gods inside Norsemens' heads (4)
41. City in China with no maritime boundaries (4)
42. Places to find 43 across and 17 across? (6)
43. Carrier of rather unnerving content (6)

**Down**
2. First of sultans in Middle-Eastern kingdom (5)
3. Small, delicate (6)
4. Showing up almost all of city in Canada's state (5)
5. One territory is country's autonomical area (5,7)
6. Painters tell a rumour kept between stars (12)
7. Unorthodox belief in this place? Silly extremists! (6)
8. Peter is 31 down, getting some sleep (3)
9. Holy cow! Stack Exchange is showing 10 down creatures (5)
10. *The Little Mermaid* broadcast on air (6)
13. Place in Italy, with love for young suitor (5)
17. Dean Martin originally misrepresented 40 across (4)
20. Waterway ending between the capitals of Wales and England (3)
22. What a 43 across did passing capital of Persia today (3)
23. Dog's breakfast eatery (4)
25. No Disney character's getting film awards (6)
27. Maybe Vespa acted in a languid way (5)
28. "Superhuman" Bitcoin crashed – fortune essentially lost (6)
30. One poor area near a border of 33 down City (6)
31. Shipping service in the United States (and in France) is distressed (5)
33. Mountain in 4 down's neighbour (5)
34. Ernie transitioned to a woman (5)
38. 40 across's issue with nonexistent hotel network (3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

Comment: Nice work! In 41a I was thinking of the official spelling (starting with an X), but it looks like it works with the alternative spelling as well. 7d is not intended as an &lit. 22d is missing from the clue explanations?

Comment: @jafe Ah, fixed - thanks for pointing that out! Not sure what I was thinking for the latter two there.